# how to combine a list into a matrix in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have the following data

```
[[1]]
[1] 1.0000 1.9643 4.5957

[[2]]
[1] 1.0000 2.2753 3.8589

[[3]]
[1] 1.0000 2.9781 4.5651

[[4]]
[1] 1.0000 2.9320 3.5519

[[5]]
[1] 1.0000 3.5772 2.8560

[[6]]
[1] 1.0000 4.0150 3.1937

[[7]]
[1] 1.0000 3.3814 3.4291
```

**how to convert it to a matrix of dimension 7X3?????**

Comment: Before asking a question next time show some ground work, what have you tried? What worked? What did not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `list`, one way to transform it to the `dim` as mentioned would be to use `do.call` along with `rbind`

```
 do.call(rbind, data)
```